# If G is abelian and simple, then G is cyclic.

Tags: abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, simple-groups

True/False: If a group $G$ is abelian and simple,then $G$ is cyclic.

Solution:

True. If $G$ is an abelian simple group, then $G$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p$ for some prime $p$.

Comment: Your answer is correct, although it would be useful to have an argument. Basically, if $G$ is abelian, any subgroup is normal, so an abelian simple group must only have $\{1\}$ and $G$ as subgroups.

Comment: @Thomas Andrews so how can we say that G is cyclic if G an abelian simple group that have  have {1} and G as subgroups

Comment: Hint: Pick any element $g \ne e$. What's the smallest subgroup containing $g$ and all its powers?

Answer (score 6):

Assume $G$ is abelian and simple. Then any subgroup is a normal subgroup, so the only subgroups must be $\{1\}$ and $\{G\}$ if $G$ is simple.

If $x\neq 1$ is an element of $G$, then $\langle x\rangle=\{x^k\mid k\in\mathbb Z\}$, the subgroup of $G$ generated by $x$, must be all of $G$. So $G$ is cyclic.